# check for remaining space in RAM on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, memory, ram

I am creating a program that will allocate a huge amount of data in the RAM. Now, if RAM runs out of space, the program will be put on to virtual memory and paging swap will occur. This is very slow. Is it possible to check for remaining space of RAM? And is it possible to check whether the system is now using virtual memory?

This is on C++ on Windows.

Comment: Windows will agressively try to use all available RAM, filling it with disk cache if there's no program actively using it.

Comment: All memory in Windows in vitual. You are probably wanting to know if your program as be swaped out to disk.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: you know? You are probably right...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [GlobalMemoryStatusEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to get the amount of free RAM. To get a notification when you are running out of RAM you can use [QueryMemoryResourceNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366799%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method.

Comment: Are there alternatives in the case that windows.h is not available?

Comment: why wouldn't windows.h be available?

Comment: For instance, if you use Visual C++ express. It doesn't come with windows.h, I recalled.

Comment: I'd be surprised Visual C++ doesn't include standard windows headers. But you can always download the Win32 SDK.

Comment: @unknownthreat, Visual C++ Express (2010 at least) does come with the Windows SDK, and the IDE is configured to find it by default. You should be able to just #include "windows.h" and go.

Comment: Anyone else tried this to see if it actually works? When I tried using QueryMemoryResourceNotification and I never get a notification - even when processes are hanging due to waiting to allocate memory.

Answer (score 1):

Just having the amount of free ram doesn't mean windows will not page your program.  You can try the SetProcessWorkingSetSize api for GetCurrentProcess, but it doesn't provide a guarantee, you can instead use VirtualLock which should guarantee it, but you can get degraded perfomance.